# ASP.NET MVC 5 Entity Framework with resource files

Tags: entity-framework-5, asp.net-mvc-5, resource-files

I’m creating a ASP.NET MVC 5 website with data entity framework database.
I'm using language resource-files to display names and validate texts.

Now I have a database with a class in which I want to refer to the resource-file. So that if you choose another language, the content changes automatically.

Like this:

Class:

```
 public class status
    {
        public int statusID { get; set; }
        public Resources.validation name { get; set; }

    }
```

Define class:

```
var Test=new status;
Test.name= text;
```

In the resource file:

```
Name= text
Value= my String
```

It’s possible? Have I do this with view models?
Thank you for help.